# jQuery.Ready fires during unload - any way to prevent this?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that loads some external scripts via `defer`:

```
 <script src="externalPlugin.js" defer></script>
```

I then have some code in `jquery.ready` that calls stuff from that script

```
$(function() {
    $.externalPlugin();
});
```

So far so good, it works 99.9% of the time.

## The problem

If a user navigates away from the page (hits "refresh", or just quickly navigates to another page) **while the `externalScript` is still loading/executing** - `jQuery.ready` still gets called (!) and obviously throws this error: `$.externalPlugin is not a function` or similar.

How do I fight this?

I tried adding an `beforeunload` handler that removes the `ready` binding

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload",function() { $(document).unbind("ready"); });
```

But it does not work.

This is not a big issue (after all the user is navigating AWAY so he doesn't care about any errors), but still that's interesting behavior.

**update**

Yep, I know that I can wait the definition or even use `<script defer onload='whatever()'>` but I was wondering if there's a "global" way to fix this universally - *by not calling `.ready` if the page is being unloaded*... If not - I'd say this is actually a bug that has to be reported to jQuery team, eh?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to initiate the script on your main page in dom ready, remove the defer attribute of the script :

```
 <script src="externalPlugin.js"></script>
```

You can either wait the function définition :

```
function wait(fn, delay)
{
    var i = setInterval(function(){

        if(fn() && typeof fn() == "function")
        {
            clearInterval(i);
            fn()();
        }
    }, delay);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    wait(function(){ return $.externalPlugin }, 100);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Wait till script loaded

```
$(function() {
    waitPlugin();
});

function waitPlugin(){
    if( $.externalPlugin == null  ) {
        setTimeout(waitPlugin,1000);
        return;
    }
    $.externalPlugin();
}
```

But I would reorganize the code some way.

Comment: you're blocking the whole page for nothing. If you want to wait an initialisation use setInterval/setTimeout